# Forward declarations for record types

Tags: delphi, types

Is there such a thing as in the title?  I'm trying to do this in part of converting [an API structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and run into something I haven't encountered before:

```
PFNReaderTranslatedDispatch = function(var msg: TMsg): BOOL; stdcall;
PFNReaderScroll = function(var prmi: TReaderModeInfo; dx, dy: integer): BOOL; stdcall;
TReaderModeInfo = record
  cbSize: DWord;
  hWnd: THandle;
  fFlags: DWord;
  prc: PRect;
  pfnScroll: PFNReaderScroll;
  fFlags2: PFNReaderTranslatedDispatch;
  lParam: DWord;
end;
PReaderModeInfo = ^TReaderModeInfo;
```

Those who know Delphi will see the obvious problem.  How would you work around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is the simplest solution:

```
PFNReaderTranslatedDispatch = function(var msg: TMsg): BOOL; stdcall;
PReaderModeInfo = ^TReaderModeInfo;
PFNReaderScroll = function(prmi: PReaderModeInfo; dx, dy: integer): BOOL; stdcall;
TReaderModeInfo = record
  cbSize: DWord;
  hWnd: THandle;
  fFlags: DWord;
  prc: PRect;
  pfnScroll: PFNReaderScroll;
  fFlags2: PFNReaderTranslatedDispatch;
  lParam: DWord;
end;
```

Indeed, you can clearly reaplce a `var` parameter by a (by-value) pointer parameter. And there is no problem declaring `PReaderModeInfo` before `TReaderModeInfo`.

Comment: Thanks!  Now to go implement!

Comment: This is the only way, I searched for a solution once too for this exact scenario. And it only applies if you intend to use the pointer version.

Comment: Just a note, it should be possible to make `prmi` an untyped `var` parameter too if it's important to call the function without an explicit pointer. You of course lose type safety, which is why I wouldn't do it myself, but others might, so just making sure it's mentioned here.